# make a pop-up window in php

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I am having trouble with this piece of php code, right now it just showing a list of fields.
how do I make this a pop-up window in php?
I tried inserting javascript, but php+javascript together really confused me. thanks so much for the help!!!

```
$output .= '
<div class="item-list">
<ul><li class="first">
<a target="_blank" href="/drupall/user/register" title="Create a new user account.">Create new    account</a></li>
<li class="last">
<a href="/drupall/user/password" title="Request new password via e-mail.">Request new password</a></li>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to incorporate javascript in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518518/best-way-to-incorporate-javascript-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
"<"a href = "popup.html" target = "_blank" onclick="popupCode();return false;" ">"
```

Should open a popup if you've got javascript on; otherwise open in a blank window
w/o quotes around the `">"` and `"<"` Leave all other quotes there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

```
$onclick = "onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'New Account');return false;\"";
$output .= '<a target="_blank" href="/drupall/user/register"' . 
            $onclick . 'title="Create a new user account.">Create new account</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use info pop up, you can do like this:

```
$text= 'Some thing to apear on the pop up!';

echo "<script>alert('".$text."')</script>";
```

If you want more fancy pop up use bootstrap modal:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals